# which keyword Can i find my app on play store?

Tags: react-native

I published my app on play store and I can find my app with just my applicationId which is in `build.grandle`.

When I change my `applicationId`, application is not working. I dont know keyword is `applicaonId` or not. If it is, how can i change ? if it is not, how can i define keyword for my app ?

Answer (score 0):

You only have one applicationId and it cannot change. Title, subtitle, description of the app are used as keyword. Play store has a one day propagation service, so you might wait 24h after publication before finding your app with keywords.

You can check this article to learn more about PlayStore SEO: https://medium.com/@gabrielmachuret/how-to-do-google-play-store-optimization-for-your-android-app-e94063b72b62